# Are all Eldritch Invocations nullified by an antimagic field?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, antimagic-field, eldritch-invocations

In one of the tables I'm part of, we engaged in a discussion about an *[antimagic field](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/antimagic-field)* being able to nullify the effects of an warlock's *Devil's Sight* because [Eldritch Invocations](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/warlock#EldritchInvocations) are magical in nature (*Player's Handbook*, page 107 - emphasis mine):

> In your study of occult lore, you have unearthed eldritch invocations, fragments of forbidden knowledge that imbue you with an abiding **magical ability**.

Nothing in its descriptions contradicts the only "hole" of the *antimagic field* description, that is:

> Spells and other magical effects, except those created by an artifact or a deity are suppressed in the sphere and can't protrude into it.

The *[Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf)* includes a list of questions to see if something is magical, then, that something is indeed blocked by an *antimagic field* (emphasis mine).

> - Is it a magic item?
> - Is it a spell? Or does it let you create the effects of a spell that’s mentioned in its description?
> - Is it a spell attack?
> - Is it fueled by the use of spell slots?
> - **Does its description say it’s magical?**

Since the Eldritch Invocations feature description says they are magical, are all eldritch invocations nullified by an *antimagic field*?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Yes.

As you have stated, Eldritch Invocations are *magical*, and unless they are created by an *artifact*, or *deity*, i.e. the casting is through an artifact, or cast directly by the deity, then it will not work in, or protrude into an anti-magic field.