# Is a weapon infused with an Artificer's Infusions a magic weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, artificer, eberron

For example, the artificer's "Radiant Weapon" infusion gives +1 to attack and damage. Does it count as a magic weapon?

Comment: Potentially related: [Is a Warlock's Improved Pact Weapon considered a magic weapon?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/171859/56975)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Yes

The [Infuse Item feature](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/artificer#ClassFeatures) states:

> you gain the ability to imbue mundane items with certain magical infusions. The **magic items** you create with this feature are effectively prototypes of permanent items.

Additionally, the specific Radiant Weapon infusion says:

> This **magic weapon** grants a +1 bonus to attack and damage rolls made with it.

<sup>(all emphases are added by me)</sup>